# advantages and disadvantages of Upgrading a custom feature using "FeatureUpgrade" approach in Sharepoint 2010 through code

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013

I am new to Sharepoint.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of upgrading a custom feature using "FeatureUpgrade" approach in Sharepoint 2010 through code?